# I have a confusion about the following code that use poll function in POSIX

Tags: linux

Following code is a TCP server.

```
bool Run()
{   
    bool result = false;
    m_Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (INVALIDE_SOCKET == m_Socket)
    {
        printf("Invalide socket...");
        return result;
    }

    sockaddr_in servAddr;
    unsigned int sockAddrSize = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
    bzero(&servAddr, sockAddrSize);
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(m_Port);

    if (0 != bind(m_Socket, (sockaddr *)&servAddr, sockAddrSize))
    {
        printf("Can not bind socket addres to socket file...\n");
        return result;
    }

    if (0 != listen(m_Socket, MAX_CONNECTION))
    {
        printf("Can not listen socket...\n");
        return result;
    }


    printf("Server is stared. Please enter any key to continue...\n");
    getchar();
    system("clear");

    m_Listener.Start();
    m_DataReader.Start();

    sockaddr_in temp;
    while (true)
    {
        bzero(&temp, sockAddrSize);
        int tempSocket = accept(m_Socket, (sockaddr *)&temp, &sockAddrSize);

        if (-1 == tempSocket)
        {
            printf("accept is fialed...\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("A connection is established!\n");
        }

        //This is my intention:blocking after the client is connected and before the client to be send any data. 
        //When the client sends data, the program will print '---------------'.
        pollfd tempTest;
        tempTest.events = POLLRDNORM;
        tempTest.revents = 0;
        tempTest.fd = tempSocket;

        int pollRes = poll(&tempTest, 1, -1);
        if (pollRes == 1 && POLLRDNORM == tempTest.revents)
        {
          printf("-------------------\n");
        }

    }
    return  result;
}
```

In fact , when a client is connected to the server and do not send any data,following codes do not meet my intention,because it is not blocked and printed '--------------' also:

```
    //This is my intention:blocking after the client is connected and before the client to be send any data. 
    //When the client sends data, the program will print '---------------'.
    pollfd tempTest;
    tempTest.events = POLLRDNORM;
    tempTest.revents = 0;
    tempTest.fd = tempSocket;

    int pollRes = poll(&tempTest, 1, -1);
    if (pollRes == 1 && POLLRDNORM == tempTest.revents)
    {
      printf("-------------------\n");
    }
```

Comment: This is obviously not your real code. This will not even compile, due to `follfd` not being defined.

Comment: Use `perror` in all error cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) man page?

You should test the result of `poll` so code:

```
fflush(NULL);
int res = poll(&test, 1, -1);
if (res < 0) {
  perror("poll");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /// or some other error handling
};
printf("poll gave %d\n", res);
```

BTW, I would call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) before polling, and I would print the result of `poll` at least for debugging purposes.

You certainly want to handle `follfd.revents` after a successful `poll`; you should care notably if it is `POLLNVAL` or `POLLERR`.

You should also test [socket(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) likewise (and you should [bind(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) or [connect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) it before `poll`ing, see [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) and maybe [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) or [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html); I guess this is why `poll` is failing or saying `POLLNVAL` or `POLLERR`!)

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: Thank for your answer . I have been eliminate the confusion.